# Accessing a Javabean property using <s:property>

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a JSP and I want to fill some fields with information from my `Action` class.
In my `Action` class I have a `PersonDTO` object.
It's some example code only to get a picture of the design

```
int id = 4;
Person result = findMyRowFromDb(id);    
PersonDTO personDTO = new PersonDTO(result);
return "fillForm"
```

So in my JSP I want to get the values from my object.
I write something like

```
<input type="text" name="PersonName" id="PersonName"
    value='<s:property value="personDTO.name"/>'/>
```

`name` is a field of my `PersonDTO` object.
But nothing is displayed.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does your action class have a `getPersonDTO()` method?

Comment: no, i edit my post, name is a field from my DTO object

Comment: Perhaps you should post more of your action class code.  As Steven Benitez said, you need a `getPersonDTO()` method in your action class and a `getName()` method in your PersonDTO class.

Comment: I don't do Struts2, but in the end you (or Struts2) should be placing the `personDTO` instance in the request scope to get JSP to see it.

Comment: i have both methods in my class (getter for PersonDTO and for Name)

Comment: Show your action code and the PersonDTO code. You don't need a `getName()` method on your action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as doctrey mentioned, to display the `<s:property value="personDTO.name"/>` value, `personDTO` have to be an instance variable of your action class and also in `PersonDTO` class there should be a getter method for the `name` attribute. If so you will see your result.

And also you don't have to use `<s:property>` here, you can use `<s:textfield>` tag like following,

```
<s:textfield id="PersonName" name="personDTO.name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Steven and nmc said for every variable you want to access on your page you need to expose it with a getter method like `getPersonDTO()` in your case.
But assuming your code is in `execute` method the `personDTO` is a local variable and cannot be returned by a getter. So first you have to declare it as instance variable then provide a getter method.